# Hyper-V CentOS 7 guest has no keyboard in recovery modes

Tags: centos, hyper-v, systemd, keyboard

I am working with CentOS 7 as a Generation 2 guest on Hyper-V 2012 R2. Everything runs fine, but I am unable to control the guest when I boot it into certain systemd targets. For instance, if I were to use GRUB2 to specify...

```
systemd.unit=emergency.target
```

or

```
systemd.unit=rescue.target
```

the machine will boot into those modes, but my keyboard does nothing. From the few clues I have found online, it looks like Hyper-V supplies keyboard/mouse control as USB HID, and the appropriate kernel module might not be loaded.

Does anyone know of a fix for this? I would prefer to keep the kernel/grub files as they are, and specify the additional module I need (if that's what is breaking this) via the GRUB2 menu when I actually need to boot into these modes.

Thanks!